# windll ctypes call variadic c function from python 2.7 works in win64 but not in win32

Tags: python, windows, ctypes, 32bit-64bit, variadic-functions

I'm using Python 2.7 on Windows 10-32 and Windows 10-64.

I'm writing a python wrapper to a C compiled stdcall (Windows) DLL (= mydll). I have 2 versions of the DLL - 32 and 64 bit.
The 64 version works great using `windll.mydll`.
The 32 version works great using the same command for all functions on the DLL, except for variadic `printf`-like functions.

When running `mydll.myvarfunc("Hello")`

I get
`ValueError: Procedure probably called with too many arguments (4 bytes in excess)`

Is there a way around this that does not involve changing the C code for the variadic functions?

Comment: Just to check: you are calling your 32-bit DLL from 32-bit Python, aren't you?

Comment: On Win64, there is only one ABI so WinDLL and CDLL make no difference. On Win32, variadic functions are cdecl not stdcall so WinDLL is using the wrong calling convention.

Comment: BoarGules: I'm using 32bit dll on 32 bit python yes. Mark Tolonen: I've noticed that when I load the file with CDLL the variadic funcs do work but the rest of the functions do not. So your recommendation is just to load the file twice - use the WinDLL instance for the non-variadic and the CDLL for the variadic?

Comment: @jreing, note that creating both `ctypes.CDLL` and `ctypes.WinDLL` instances doesn't physically load the DLL twice. It just creates a 2nd reference to the same DLL in memory. Alternatively, you can create individual cdecl function pointers. Use a prototype such as `fn_cdecl_p = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_int)`.  Instantiate the prototype for each function, and set it as an attribute of `mydll`, e.g. `setattr(mydll, 'myvarfunc', fn_cdecl_p(('myvarfunc', mydll))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Win64, there is only one ABI so WinDLL and CDLL make no difference. On Win32, variadic functions are always `__cdecl` so WinDLL is using the wrong calling convention.

One way to work around this:

```
import ctypes
stdcall_func = ctypes.WinDLL('mydll').stdcall_func
cdecl_func = ctypes.CDLL('mydll').cdecl_func
```