# Calling convention on msvcrt with ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes, calling-convention

I am tryning to play with Python ctypes. I am surprised to see that the following code:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> ctypes.windll.msvcrt.printf(b"Hello World!")
Hello World!
```

works like a charm.

I am loading the *msvcrt* library with a *windll* object that is used to load libraries with the *stdcall* convention. This example is taken from [ctypes documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#calling-functions) where it said it should actually fail every time.

Am I missing something?
I am on a Windows 10 machine with an Intel 64-bits CPU and tried it on Python 2.7 and 3.7 (CPython).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/50386340/222914

Comment: Cannot upvote but indeed on Win64, there's only one ABI, so using cdll or windll does not make any difference.